# Обновление блока без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Здарствуйте, у меня есть блок который получает даные от Rails приложения, но на сайте они появляются только после перезагрузки страницы, как реализовать так чтобы все это обновлялось сразу? может можно задать интервал, к примеру 100 и тогда оно будет оновлятся, или только получать ответ с файла и даные которые ajax должен подгрузить?

Comment: А как приложение реализовано? Rails — это лишь API или ассеты (JS+CSS) тоже собираются Rails приложением?

Comment: У меня есть несколько джобсов, после выполнения джобса по конвертированию файлов, хочу чтобы конвертированые файлы выводились в соседнем блоке возле оригиналов, но они выводятся только после оновления страницы.

Comment: А можете полный цикл работы описать? Т е что передается на сервер, асинхронно или синхронно, делается ли запись в БД...